# Canon SLR photos not uploading from iPhoto to Photo Stream

Tags: photos, photos.app, photo-stream, streaming

I uploaded photos from my Canon SLR camera to my iPhoto library last night at 7pm and it is the next day (3pm) and my photos have yet to show up in my Photo Stream album.  I have taken pictures with my iPhone since last night and those have uploaded just fine to my photo stream album but NO photos from non-Apple devices.  It is very frustrating because it has worked just fine before but now it is not.

Comment: Is Photo Stream *uploading* turned on in iPhoto preferences? The third checkbox in this image: https://support.apple.com/library/content/dam/edam/applecare/images/en_US/ios/iphoto/photo_stream.png

Comment: Hmm - I wonder if a switch was thrown by Apple relating to all the software that was released today. What version of iPhoto and what OS X?